# Is it possible to assign a case to a queue and assign a date/time?

Tags: event

Is it possible to assign a case to a queue and assign a date/time?

We are currently migrating from a private CRM to Salesforce, and one of the requirements is being able to schedule our customers to be called, we have fairly small teams and we can't have the team's appointments overlap, they also work mostly casual so it's not predictable who works what days.

Is this possible?

NOTE: I already figured the "dummy user" solution, which seems like a hacky work around

Answer (score 1):

[Queues](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/queues_overview.htm) are definitely part of the Salesforce platform. From the documentation:

> Queues help your teams manage leads, cases, service contracts, and
>   custom objects. Once records are placed in a queue manually or through
>   an automatic case or lead assignment rule, records remain there until
>   they're assigned to a user or taken by one of the queue members. Any
>   queue member or users above them in the role hierarchy can take
>   ownership of records in a queue. For example:
>
> **Case Queues**
>
> Help you manage your support workload and differentiate cases based on
>   support levels. With queues, you can ensure that cases are resolved
>   quickly even if a specific user is on vacation. By creating queues for
>   different support levels, such as Gold Service and Silver Service,
>   cases are automatically prioritized. You can put cases in different
>   queues, either manually or automatically via a case assignment rule as
>   cases are generated from the Web or created manually. Make support
>   agents members of case queues.

For more information on getting started working with queues, check out the [Creating Queues documentation](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/setting_up_queues.htm). I also found this [Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hK2U_pOrwcI) which may help.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, I have some queues created, but I would like to assign an event to a queue, not a user